# Is there a common theme between modulus, moduli and modulo?

Tags: soft-question

The moduli space is some sort of space of parameterizing space, modulo as in modular arithmetic and modulus as in the modulus of a complex number.

Is there a reason all these words are the so similar?

Comment: I imagine Maria Callas singing on the theme modulus modulo moduli :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They all have the same root. "[Modulus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/modulus#Latin)" means "measure"; a modulus is a measure of something. The modulus of a complex number measures its length as a vector. The term "modular arithmetic" comes from [Gauss](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/m/) who used "modulus" as follows:

> Si numerus a numerorum b, c differentiam metitur, b et c secundum a congrui dicuntur, sin minus, incongrui; ipsum a modulum appelamus. Uterque numerorum b, c priori in casu alterius residuum, in posteriori vero nonresiduum vocatur. [If a number $a$ **measure the difference** [emphasis mine] between two numbers $b$ and $c$, $b$ and $c$ are said to be congruent with respect to $a$, if not, incongruent; $a$ is called **the modulus** [emphasis mine], and each of the numbers $b$ and $c$ the residue of the other in the first case, the non-residue in the latter case.]

So in modular arithmetic $n$ is the modulus and working $\bmod n$ means measuring the difference between two integers in units of $n$. Remember that the Western mathematical tradition is deeply steeped in Euclidean geometry and for over a thousand years a number was a length. "Measuring the difference" means that $n$ divides the difference but the term "measuring" is meant (I believe, anyway) to evoke the geometric picture of a stick of length $n$ being used to literally measure the length of the difference.

"Moduli" is the plural of modulus so "moduli space" should be interpreted as "space of moduli," in the sense that a moduli space describes all possible ways an object of some type can vary (and we can *measure* these variations).